# Laravel relationtable with many to many

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relational-database

Im stuck on how to connect my users with other tables in a clean way. I've tried to work with laravel polymorphic table handling without success. This is what my tables look like, ( ignore the plural use of equipment and armor, will change later).

A user will have many equipments which points to one weapon or armor.

```
:: users ::
id
name

:: equipment ::
id
user_id
equipment_id
equipment_type

:: weapons ::
id
name

:: armors ::
id
name
```

What i would like to do is to get weapons and armors of users

```
$user->weapons ( Should return all weapons )
$user->armors ( Should return all armors )
```

Inside my DB i have 2 records inside the equipment table:

```
id: 1
user_id: 21 (current user)
equipment_id = 1 (id of a weapon in weapons table)
equipment_type = weapon (string)

id: 2
user_id: 21 (current user)
equipment_id = 2 (id of a weapon in weapons table)
equipment_type = weapon (string)
```

This is my current attempt using larvel polymorphic tables

UserModel:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
  public function weapons()
  {
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Weapon', 'equipment');
  }
}
```

WeaponModel:

```
class Weapon extends Model
{  
    public function users()
    {
     return $this->morphToMany('App\User', 'equipment');
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to define the relationship to do this

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta What do you mean with define the relationship? Could you provide an example thanks.

Comment: you had made a relationship with equipment with the user on user_id similarly, you have to make the relationship with equipment to armor and weapons models

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta Alright i understand, that makes sense. Do you think i should use morphToMany inside equipment to armor and weapons or what do you think i should handle this to also get the right via equipmentable_type

Comment: Use https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I have tried following the documentation and i'am getting an empty collection. I will update the question with what i tried doing. Please check if you have time

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta  I have updated the answer with a new way and also whats inside my equipment table. Could you check if you see anything wrong.

Comment: Are you using a custom `Relation::morphMap()`? If not, `equipment_type` has to contain the class names: `App\Weapon`, `App\Armor`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Thanks A LOT, this was it, i thought i was setting the names but i wasn't... I created a Relation::morphMap()  and defined them and that worked. Set this as an answer if you want the credit. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `equipment_type` column has to contain the whole class name, e.g. `App\Weapon`.

Alternatively, you can define a custom `$morphMap` in `AppServiceProvider::boot()`:

```
Relation::morphMap([
    'armor' => 'App\Armor',
    'weapon' => 'App\Weapon',
]);
```